# Timestamp in C++

Tags: c++, timestamp, runtime

I want to know the run time of a program using timestamp to test how long does a certain program or block of code to execute. I don't understand the concept of timestamp, as I keep on reading the definition and its uses of timestamp, I moreover come across with displaying the current date and time which is somehow not helpful to solve my case. I am looking forward to be enlightened with this topic. Have a nice day! Thank you!

Comment: Reminder, there are other activities occurring in the system that may impact your program's execution.  One activity is higher priority tasks (these get "switched out" with your program).  Another is usage of the data bus (by other cores and hardware components).  You'll have to settle for an average duration.  A simple measurement would involve a minimum of 1.0E6 iterations.  Search the internet for "Benchmarking c++ programs"

Comment: Dude, what's the difference of timestamp with benchmarking? As I can read some comments, both of them fit well to know the Big O notation of a certain block of code, yet this can't be similar. Hoping to enlighten me with this matter, thank you!

Comment: A timestamp is a point in time. How it's encoded and the resolution varies. Two timestamps can be used to compute the distance between them, the elapsed time.

Comment: Time complexity doesn't relate well to time. Big O only tells you how much more work is likely to happen as you increase the input size. Given an elapsed time tor a data set and a known time complexity you can estimate how long the same operation on a dataset of a different size should take, but that's about it.

Comment: Benchmarking is measuring the performance of a program or a part of a program. A timestamp is a point in time.  You may need to run code many times between timestamps in order to get a valid duration (for example, if your timestamp resolution is in milliseconds, but the code is running in nanoseconds).  The benchmarking process includes information on how to handle anomalies, such as task swapping.  Remember to verify the optimization level of the build before profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have a clock. If you check the time and write it down into a paper, that is a timestamp. Just before you start some activity you can write down the current time and then start your activity. After you finish it, you look at the clock again and write down the new timestamp. Then you can compute the difference of both your timestamps to see how long that activity took to be finished.

In C++ you can use the [chrono library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) for that.
The program below is an example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;
using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // That's your first time stamp
    auto tic = Clock::now();

    // Some complicated code

    // That is your second timestamp
    auto toc = Clock::now();

    // Compute the difference between the timestamps and cast it to a number
    // expressing the difference into some unit (how many milliseconds that
    // difference is).
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(toc - tic).count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Computing the difference between timestamps like this is one possible way to benchmark some part of your code. Of course the duration is affected by other things such as the load in your system, etc. Usually you want to run the same code block many times in a loop and average the duration to get a better estimation.

Comment: Note: `chrono` is limited by what support it gets from the underlying system. While it offers nanosecond resolution it often cannot reach nanosecond precision. Sometimes the best you can get is tens of milliseconds, and that's not good enough to time work performed by computers that can do billions of things a second unless you give that computer billions of things to do.